# When do we charge our customers in CMA and LMA app?

Tags: lma, cma

When our subscribe install our package ,CMA and LMA provides us a feature where we let user pay after installation.What does after installation means here?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Do I collect customer payment details before or after installation?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_checkout_faq_stripe_lma.htm) you would collect the payment details afterwards if you want the installation to be quicker and to then manage the trial of the application via the LMA.

The ISVForce Guide is otherwise sparse on the implications of deferring the payment to sometime after installation has occured.